# Error while running test in Robotframework docker container

Tags: docker, testing, robotframework

While running my tests in robotframework docker container, I am receiving below error. I have downloaded the latest robotframework image from docker hub. Trying since long, but no success.

**Background** - The tests were running fine. But someone deleted our robot image and container from server, so had to create new container from docker hub image. Also, no one is aware if any customization was done on earlier image. Kindly guide if any library/package missing to be installed in the container.

```
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5cd6b54a00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve')': /session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5cd653a820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve')': /session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5cd653b9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve')': /session
```

Comment: Need more information. What image you use (exact label)? Did you update the system? The message is at Warn level, should not be blocking. Is the container properly configured for network connections?

Comment: I used the 'latest' label for pulling the docker image of robotframework. It is blcking as the tests dont proceed and fails saying connection error. Is there anything specific to be done at container level for network connection? I can ping to the internet url from my robot container and also to my test url. Anything specific to be configured.?

Comment: Probably is outdated, last update was 2 years ago. Maybe you should try to use this newer one: https://github.com/ppodgorsek/docker-robot-framework

Comment: Ok, I did. And same error. After above WARN messages, I have below error, does it relate to test scripts or relates to docker/robot?

Comment: Login_with_invalid_credentials                                        | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='false', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f83c3948e20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve'))

Comment: Deeper troubleshooting is needed. Open a ` bash`  in the container and run tests manually using loglevel DEBUG. Try to understand why urllib3 is failing. Try to use the IP address, because `Name does not resolve` . See docker help for configuring DNS resolver.